# How to aggregate a dataframe with chr column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe in R that aggregates three columns.

The first is date, the second is a chr code, and the third is num. For ever promo_code I need it to create a new column that indicates that the promo code has been used (1 = yes, 0 = no)

The promo_codes are in the thousands, so I need something that scales on its own. I can not manually add the columns

```
DATA:
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Date          | Promo_Code | Sales_Amount | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   pc20     |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |            |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |            |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+


NEW DATAFRAME
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      Date     | today20    | vip20        |  pc20        | Sales Total  |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   1        |   1          |    0         |  150.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   0        |   1          |    0         |  100.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   0        |   0          |    1         |   25.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       | ....         |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       | ....         |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
out = setDT(data)[,lapply(.SD, sum), by=data$Date]
```

Which gives this error: Type 'character' not supported

```
library(dplyr)
out = data %>% group_by(date) %>% summerise_each(funs(sum))
```

Which gives me the same error that "invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: please post `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` if it's a large dataset.  it's hard to work with data in the format you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that adds a count for each `Promo_Code` in a given date, and then pivots wide to represent promo codes as their own columns.  Aggregating by date yields the total `Sales_Amount` plus `Promo_Code` counts.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Date, Promo_Code) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            Sales_Amount = sum(Sales_Amount)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Date, Sales_Amount), names_from = Promo_Code, 
              values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = sum))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Date       Sales_Amount  pc20 vip20 today20
  <date>            <dbl> <int> <int>   <int>
1 2020-10-27          115     1     1       0
2 2020-10-28           75     1     1       0
3 2020-10-29           60     1     1       0
4 2020-10-30          115     1     1       0
5 2020-10-31          100     1     0       1
```

Example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(Date = rep(seq(ymd('2020-10-27'),ymd('2020-10-31'), by = '1 day'), 2),
             Promo_Code = sample(c("today20", "vip20", "pc20"), replace=T, 10),
             Sales_Amount = sample(c(25, 35, 50, 65, 75), replace=T, 10))

df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Date       Promo_Code Sales_Amount
   <date>     <chr>             <dbl>
 1 2020-10-27 pc20                 65
 2 2020-10-28 pc20                 25
 3 2020-10-29 pc20                 35
 4 2020-10-30 vip20                50
 5 2020-10-31 pc20                 75
 6 2020-10-27 vip20                50
 7 2020-10-28 vip20                50
 8 2020-10-29 vip20                25
 9 2020-10-30 pc20                 65
10 2020-10-31 today20              25
```